# How do atoms scatter X-rays?

Tags: diffraction, crystals, x-rays, x-ray-crystallography

I am learning the theory behind X-ray diffraction but I have a question. According to the textbook I am using, X-ray tubes (in diffractometers) produce near monochromatic X-rays. In other words, they produce X-rays of nearly the same wavelength. Then, these X-rays interact with the electrons of atoms in a crystal lattice. The atom, in return, spherically emanates X-rays of the **same wavelength** as the X-rays from the diffractometer tube (elastic scattering). How exactly does elastic scattering work? Why do atoms accept incoming X-rays and then produce X-rays of the same wavelength in a spherical pattern? I am guessing that this is a somewhat advanced physics question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way to think about this is that the electric field of the incoming photon "wiggles" the electron, and that this wiggling electron then produces an emission of electromagnetic radiation. This is called [Thomson scatter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_scattering). Note that the emission is not isotropic - some directions will see greater intensity than others. All that is explained in detail at the link given.

Comment: Excellent. This is just what I was looking for.